# Can you transfer a complete Windows 10 "work session" to your laptop?

Tags: windows-10

So I'm at my PC and have couple of Programs and Files opened.

Then I want to continue working on my Laptop. Given that:

- My Laptop has the exact same Programs installed
- Both Computers have
  access to the same cloud storage mapped as Network Drive to the same
  Drive Letter
- Both Computers run Windows 10 Pro

Is there any way to transfer my complete work-session to my laptop "one click" back an forth?
Commercial solutions are acceptable!

Comment: You _might_ be able to do it if you hibernate your work session, then transfer the physical disc to your laptop, hardware permitting. I don't know what will happen on waking up on different hardware: there will no doubt be lots of hardware reconfigurations and possible licensing issues, and you may find it better to copy the hibernated disc and work with the copy, so as to retain the original working system disc. I doubt it will work, but you could experiment with just copying `hiberfil.sys` if both systems have the same RAM and derive from a common image, but back up **everything** first.

Comment: No. The only thing you can do is use RDP to connect to another computer from both systems and work like that, or use VirtualBox and put everything inside a container. VirtualBox allows to transfer a running session to another VirtualBox install.

Comment: @AFH how do you propose to copy hiberfil.sys? A computer in hibernation is turned off, and that file is locked by windows even if you try to get to it otherwise. Linux users have complained about not being able to boot linux due to the presence of a hiberfil.sys file.

Comment: @LPChip - Good point - VB seems a more convincing solution.

Comment: Well I was more looking for a software solution that does this job for me in a "Batch" / "Macro" style approach. Like: Check for all open programs, files, etc., wrap it all together, on the target machine process the batch, open all those programs, website tabs, copy the files.. there's so many solutions out there, I thought I might get lucky and someone made it already.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do this directly.  There are a variety of technical issues preventing this from working, such as open files, memory states, etc.

As mentioned in the comments, the easiest thing to do would be to use a remote desktop program such as Windows Remote Desktop, TeamViewer, or VNC to access and use the PC's desktop and vice versa.

A shared virtual machine would work inefficiently.  Hosting one locally would mean a third copy of the OS and programs would be needed and extra machine resources would be used.  Transferring the machine image and state would take time.  Installing the software on a VPS would be more flexible, but costlier.